# Drupal 6 custom page templates fighting each other

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a page template: page-lcds.tpl.php which works for the www.xxx.com/lcds page.

But, it also gets used for /lcds/2-4in and /lcds/5-10in and etc.

So I could create a page-lcds-2-4in.tpl.php but then I'd have to create all the others for each category.

All of these pages are actual custom Pages content-type.

Is there a better way/place to specify a page template just for "page-lcds" and then use the regular page.tpl.php file for all other lcds/*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you should treat LCD as category instead of content type.

So, create a vocabulary called "Product type" & add "LCD","LED" terms to it.

Now, you can do category theming under `page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php`
and node theming under `page-node-<custom-content-type>.tpl.php`

Comment: ah... I haven't dived into Taxonomy yet. I'm five months in to my Drupal learning and inherited a large Drupal 6 site for my first. What I've skimmed on Taxonomy sounds like a good way to track stuff by easy terms! Thanks for the suggestions. Actually, what I just figured out to be the absolute fastest was to just change the url to the specific page and rename the template accordingly. But, I'm going to use this idea on some new stuff, so thanks!